# What is the impact of increasing startId in Android foreground service?

Tags: android, performance, foreground-service

I'm using the foreground service in my android application. And i'm overriding the service's method **onStartCommand** as below :

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
// doing my staff here
}
```

As [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand(android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int)) said :

> Called by the system every time a client explicitly starts the service
>   by calling startService(Intent), providing the arguments it supplied
>   and a unique integer token representing the start request.

And

> startId   int: A unique integer representing this specific request to
>   start. Use with stopSelfResult(int).

I'm using the service correctly and service is working properly.

**My question is :**

Every time i start the service, the startId is increasing as    documentation said. What i'm not clear about is what will be the    impact of startId increasing ? Does it taking more memory or will it    effects to app performance ? (e.g what if startId is increasing over 1000 ? )

Comment: it is used in `Service#stopSelfResult(int startId)`, its just an an ID, nothing more

Comment: Do you start the same service miltiple times from you application ? Why would you do this ? Explain about your case then i can answer

Comment: @AmirZiarati whats wrong with it? how would you pass a new request to `IntentService` without it?

Comment: @pskink there isnt anything wrong with it. I was just going to ensure you know what you do. Cuz every call to service will be a pieace of work and and this ID is an ID for that pieace of work . It may increase te memory use if the previous tasks are still working and ID is not a sign of this phenamenon.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a token just an ID like the request id in `startActivityByResult`.

In case you start a service multiple times you can have a handle to them by this token to each of them.

Assume you call start service two times and then want to stop the second call! You will need something to refer that second and that something is this ID.

Increasing this ID cant be a sign of memory leak or anything its just an ID. But cases in which you will need to start a service multiple times in an application are rare. So take care of what you do. Don't start multiple instance of a single service if you don't really need it.

Comment: `"Assume you call start service two times and then want to stop the second instance"` not really, a service cannot have a "second" instance, its a signleton